# Metropolis theme: Change font size of institution on title page

Tags: beamer

I am using the metropolis beamer theme (https://github.com/matze/mtheme). 
I am creating a title page at the beginning, which includes my institution. By default, the institution is set in a smaller font than the other parts. I would like to re-size it to normal size. Embedding it in a `\begin{normalsize}` environment does not work.

I have read the manual for customization but I cannot find it. Does anyone know how to to that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the font size like the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\institute{institute}
\setbeamerfont{institute}{size=\normalsize}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```